# Calculating % change between two z-scores - correct?

Tags: percentage, z-score, pre-post-comparison

just a quick question I was a little unsure about. Any thoughts much appreciated!

Say I am running an 2 condition experimental trial where one of the outcomes is a z-score (e.g. cognitive test measured pre and post each condition).

To make the results more 'meaningful', would it be Kosher/correct to calculate the % difference in the z-score between the 2 conditions? To show there was x % difference in the z-scores between the 2 conditions.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-scores can easily be 0, so I don't think that's a safe thing to do.

A difference between them should be enough in your case. That has the advantage of interpretability as well.

Comment: Thanks - yes good point! I thought a % change perhaps might make the difference between interventions a bit more interpretable (i.e. x% reduction in cognitive function) - but not if invalid (due to the potential for zero values).